# How to send an email with Ansible

Tags: email, yaml, ansible

I'm trying to send an email using Ansible, but I can't understand how it works as I don't know how to provide user and password for such service (not specified in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/mail_module.html)).

Both my machine and the email server are in the same network, but I need to be authenticated in order to send the email.

This is my yml file:

```
--- 
- name: Testing email
  hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
    - name: Send email
      local_action: mail
        host=mail.server.com
        port=993
        subject="Ansible test mail"
        body="Testing email"
        from=my@email
        to="y@email
        charset=utf8
```

And this is the related content of the hosts' file:

```
[localhost]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

Any idea about how should I configure it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the `mail` module ( https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/d1effecb2ef073e478c67a7ca39cf56708a66a48/library/notification/mail ) it doesn't look like it supports SMTP authentication.

It shouldn't be too hard to add support for it however. It would require adding the username and password parameters to the module, detecting if they've both been supplied, and if so, calling `smtp.login()` with those parameters.

In fact, it looks like there's *two* pull requests to do exactly that at the moment here

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7213

and here

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/6667

So support will most likely be added in dev soon.